# SQLite - Filter record based on specific calculated sum

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm given a table with a varying number of records that contain persons, their weight, and an order value which determines in which order the persons should be chosen ...

```
create table line (
      id int not null PRIMARY KEY,
      name varchar(255) not null,
      weight int not null,
      turn int unique not null,
      check (weight > 0)
  );
```

I have to retrieve the last record from the table with which 1000 lbs is not exceeded when counting the person's weight together in `order`.

E.g. if the table is

```
id | name                | weight  | order |
---+---------------------+---------+-------+
5  | Mark                |   250   |   1   |
4  | James               |   175   |   5   |
3  | John                |   350   |   2   |
6  | James               |   400   |   3   |
1  | Rick                |   500   |   6   |
2  | Mike                |   200   |   4   |
```

The query should return only James, as the first three picked (per `order`) people's weight will fit within 1000 lbs. The sum of the weight of these three persons is `250 + 350 + 400 = 1000`.

People with same name might be in the table. Therefore the id should be used for the calculation.

How would I write an SQLite statement that can filter this accordingly?

I should first order by `order` but from there on my SQL knowledge is too limited to figure out how to calculate the sum within 1000...

```
SELECT name, weight, order FROM line ORDER BY order ASC
```

Comment: Why query must return `only James`? Actually that part confuses me. You want to return first 3 lines which sum of their weights is equals to 1000, isn't it? Then why query return only James?

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski I need to return the last person that fits within the 1000 lbs limit without exceeding it.

Comment: Why are there two entries for `James` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen "People with same name might be in the table. Therefore the id should be used for the calculation."

Answer (score 6):

We can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    weight,
    "order",
FROM line t1
WHERE
    (SELECT SUM(t2.weight) FROM line t2 WHERE t2."order" <= t1."order") <= 1000
ORDER BY
    "order" DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The correlated subquery in the query above calculates the running sum of weight as given by the order.  The `WHERE` clause just restricts to only line records whose cumulative weight does not exceed 1000.  Then, we order descending by the `order` column with `LIMIT 1` to target the `James` record.

By the way, avoid using SQL keywords like `order` to name your columns.

Comment: But this would return two records: Mark, John instead of the expected James (id 6).

Comment: @BadmintonCat Then use `<= 1000` if you want three records.  My answer doesn't really change.

Comment: ok thanks but how do I change it to get only the last one of the three?

Comment: Why do you keep changing your question?  Couldn't you have included this requirement _before_ anyone invested time to answer?

Comment: It was stated in my question above (The query should return only James...)

Comment: Fair enough, I must have missed that.  Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks but your last code gives me an error RUNTIME ERROR  (tested program terminated with exit code 1)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . You can get one record by adding `order by order desc limit 1` to the first query.

Answer (score 0):

SQL syntax is not case-sensitive. Wrap column name inside []: [order]

```
SELECT name, weight, order FROM line ORDER BY [order] ASC
```

Comment: This is SQL Server/Access syntax, but it won't help the OP anyway.